# List comprehensions adding a value to an element based on a condition

Tags: python

I have written code that returns the unique prime number factors of a given number.Here is that code. This code does not consider that 1 is a unique prime number. The `factorial3` is the function that returns a list of factorials for any given number.

```
 def factorials(n):
     x=[j for j in range(1, ((n/2)+1)) if n%j==0]
     x.append(n)
     return x

 n=input()
 numbers=[]
 for i in range(n):
    numbers.append(input())

 count=[0 for j in numbers]
 for i,k in enumerate(numbers):
    for j in factorial3(k):
            if factorial3(j)==[1,j]:
                    count[i]+=1
```

The list `count` gives me the unique prime numbers of numbers inputted.

For example, for 2 number 10, 20,the factors are [2,5,10] and [2,5, 10, 20]. However, the unique prime factors are [2,5] and [2,5] respectively. And hence, the count is [2,2]

I am trying to achieve the same with list comprehensions but have failed so far.This are the things that I have tried so far.

```
c=[0 for i in numbers]

new=[i+1 for i,k in enumerate(numbers) for j in factorial3(k) if factorial3(j)==[1,j]]
print new
new1=[c[i]+1 for i,k in enumerate(numbers) for j in factorial3(k) if factorial3(j)==[1,j]]
print new1
```

I am almost there, just missing the one thing cuts down the iteration just once.

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects; that's enormously wasteful as you are not actually *using* the list you built.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I just want to know how to do the list comprehensions for purpose of knowledge. I wont be using them in practical situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted to with the code below.

```
new1=[i+1 for i,k in enumerate(numbers) for j in factorial3(k) if factorial3(j)==[1,j]]

c1={}
for i in new1:
    if i not in c1:
            c1[i]=1
    else:
            c1[i]+=1

sortedc=[v for k,v in sorted(c1.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])]
x=zip(numbers, sortedc)
```

This code does not return the correct value for 1 and works perfectly fine with all other positive integers. I manually added the factorial for 1 towards the end of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the prime number factors, then simply go up to square root, rather than the whole range.

Replace your first line:

```
c=[0 for i in numbers]
```

with:

```
c=[0 for i in numbers**0.5]
```

Comment: Can you post your factorial3() function? That would help with reproducing this on other SO users' machines.

Comment: I have added the factorial3 function. Thanks !